# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64-bit and Intel Core i3

Tags: system-installation

I have a 64-bit PC with Intel Core i3. Should I install the 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my PC, since it seems that the 64-bit is for "computers based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture"?

Comment: There is no such processor "Pentium Core i3". Do you use a *Pentium* or a *Intel Core i3* processor?

Comment: For Pentium, I'd go with 32-bit Lubuntu. Ubuntu 64-bit wil run just fine on a Core i3

Comment: @grooveplex Thanks for correcting me. It indeed is Intel & not Pentium. One final question: W.r.t. heating issues, would you suggest 64-bit or 32-bit installation? Many thanks for your answer/s.

Comment: no, I should have read way better (and I will in the future). Try Ubuntu 64-bit